# Laravel showing Undefined variable in View

Tags: php, laravel

Here I have been using json to be sent to the view but all the time around I am getting Variable Undefined error where *print_r()* in the controller gives the variable value correctly and the *BB_Invoices* is the folder under *views* folder where all ***CRUD*** views are stored. The *compact()* does not show data while I have used dd() in the view while the *with()* gives the data quickly. I need to know what is the shortcut name for

```
 {{ dd(get_defined_vars()['__data']['BB_Invoices']) }}
```

for accessing BB_Invoices in the view

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use  App\Model\BB\Invoices\BB_Invoices;

class BB_InvoicesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $BB_Invoices=BB_Invoices::all()->toArray();
        $BB_Invoices=json_encode($BB_Invoices);
        //print_r($BB_Invoices);
        //return View::make('BB_Invoices.index', compact($BB_Invoices));
        //return view('BB_Invoices.index', compact($BB_Invoices));
        return view('BB.Invoices.index')->with('BB_Invoices', $BB_Invoices);
    }
}
```

and I am getting this error-

```
Undefined variable: BB_Invoices
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
return view('BB_Invoices.index', compact('BB_Invoices'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `BB.Invoices`. Just use `BB_Invoices` instead.

Also, ensure that the folder in which the index file exist is named `BB_Invoices`.

The resulting code should be:

```
return view('BB_Invoices.index')->with('BB_Invoices', $BB_Invoices);
```